# How can I subscribe to the change of components using <BrowserRouter>

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React and would like to learn a lot. I have a navigation like this:

```
<BrowserRouter >
  <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={login} />
      <Route exact path="/home" component={home} />
      <Route component={Notfound} />
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

and I want to do the typical validation that if I am in a component such as "login" the "footer" or "header" is not displayed. I think that getting the current component could make a logic to show or not the components of "header" or "footer".

I am not sure which is the best way, I have tried some things but I get "leak" problems, this is part of my code.

```
app.js
    import React from 'react';
    import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom'
    import './App.css';
    import {  home,login } from "./pages";
    import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
    const history = createBrowserHistory();
    // Listen to history changes.
    // You can unlisten by calling the constant (`unlisten()`).
    const unlisten = history.listen((location, action) => {
      console.log(action, location.pathname, location.state);
    });

    function App() {

      return (
        <BrowserRouter >
          <Switch>
           <Route exact path="/" component={login} />
           <Route exact path="/home" component={home} />
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
      );
    }

    export default App;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "leak" problem? I can see what problem you're trying solve, but I not sure precisely what part of this problem troubles you? Since I don't see what you've tried and failed, also no sight of `Header` or `Footer` in your code.

Comment: @hackape Footer and header is an example of what I want to do. "leak" this appears in the developer console, and perhaps because of my ignorance I am doing something wrong. I hope you can guide me in some way.

Comment: You can put your `header` and `footer` inside your `Home` component, that way when you are inside `Login` page the `header` and `footer` will not be shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here you have 2 doubts one is regarding header, footer and other is login token

> Solution for problem 1 (Header, Footer):

**The routing is correct and for Header Footer I would go like**

```
export default Home = props => {
  return(
    <Header />
    //Content
   <Footer />
  )
}
```

> Solution for problem 2:(To go for home if user is loggedIn)

**This approach also helps you to go back to home page if he clicks back button in home and it doesnot go to login page when he is logged in**

```
export default Login = props => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem("tokenKey");
  if(token) {
    props.history.push("home");
  }
  return(
    //content
  )
}
```

If we have problem like login page is getting loaded for some seconds and then its redirecting to Home page

> Create a separate page for checkAuthentication:

```
export default checkAuth = props => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem("tokenKey");
  return(
     {
       token ? <Home /> : <Login />
     }
  )
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203293/discussion-on-answer-by-gvs-akhil-how-can-i-subscribe-to-the-change-of-component).

Comment: can you help me with this, you are the indicated man :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59110365/when-navigating-between-a-view-a-to-a-view-b-it-automatically-returns-to-view-a

Comment: Answered your question :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is incorrect. Naming component must be capitalized. Change `login` to `Login` and change `home` to `Home`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all your header and footer need to be rendered outside of the switch statement like so:
(This will prevent weird side effects and 'leaks')

```
  <BrowserRouter >
    <Header />
    <Switch>
       <Route exact path="/" component={login} />
       <Route exact path="/home" component={home} />
    </Switch>
    <Footer />
  </BrowserRouter>
```

The best solution is to have multiple switch statements.

One in the header file.
One for your content.
One in the footer file.

Alternatively in many companies I have worked for.
We simply have conditions in the Header and Footer.

In order to have context of the route you simply use the withRouter HoC.
like so:

```
import { withRouter } from "react-router";

const Header = (props) => {
   const { match, location, history } = props;
   // This is all the data you will need for your conditions
   // return null if you want the header to be hidden
   return null;
}

export default withRouter(Header);
```

Answer (score 0):

Biggest value of React is "Component", so use components to solve your problems.

If you define  and  as components you will simply render them where you need them. I believe this is a much better solution than trying to turn them off for different routes.

Comment: I'm using a navigation, so I don't know how to apply what you say