# when navigating between a view A to a view B it automatically returns to view A using createSwitchNavigator

Tags: reactjs

This is the structure of my navigation in which I have 3 components, and I have a `sidemu` (`drawer`), but I do not want the `sidemenu` to be seen in `login`, so I place the "`Detail`" component in the "`LoginStack`" . The `sidemenu` only is showed in `Home` component.

the behavior occurs of the gif, why can this happen?

[image]

usernavigation.js

```
    import React from "react";
    import { createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator } from "react-navigation";
    import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation-stack";
    import { createDrawerNavigator } from "react-navigation-drawer";
    import SideBar from "../components/SideBar/SideBar";
    import { STYLES } from "../styles/Styles";
    import LoginScreen from "../screens/Login/Login";
    import HomeScreen from "../screens/Home/Home";
    import DetailScreen from "../screens/DetailScreen/DetailScreen ";
    //Aqui se debe incluir las screen que no deben mostrar el drawer
    const LoginStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Login: {
        screen: LoginScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: "Login",
            headerLeft: null,
            header: null
        }
        },
        Detail: {
        screen: DetailScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: "Detail container",
            headerStyle: STYLES.bgHeaderBack,
            headerTintColor: "#fff",
            headerMode: "none"
        }
        }
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: "Login"
    }
    );

    const HomeStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Home: {
        screen: HomeScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: "Home",
            headerLeft: null,
            header: null
        }
        }
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: "Home",
        headerMode: "none"
    }
    );

    const DrawerStack = createDrawerNavigator(
    {
        Home: {
        screen: HomeStack
        }
    },
    {
        contentComponent: SideBar
    }
    );

    const switchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator(
    {
        LoginStack: LoginStack,
        HomeStack: DrawerStack
    },
    {
        headerMode: "none",
        initialRouteName: "LoginStack"
    }
    );

    const AppContainer = createAppContainer(switchNavigator);
    export default AppContainer;
```

this is the component DetailScreen

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { STYLES } from "../../styles/Styles";

import {
  Container,
  Header,
  Title,
  Left,
  Icon,
  Right,
  Button,
  Body,
  Content,
  Text,
  Card,
  CardItem
} from "native-base";

const ContainerDetail = props => {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Header style={STYLES.bgAzulPatios}>
        <Left>
          <Button transparent onPress={() => props.navigation.goBack()}>
            <Icon name="arrow-back" />
          </Button>
        </Left>
        <Body>
          <Title>Detail Container</Title>
        </Body>
        <Right />
      </Header>

      <Content padder>
        <Card>
          <CardItem>
            <Body>
              <Text>Detail Container</Text>
            </Body>
          </CardItem>
        </Card>
      </Content>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default DetailScreen;
```

this is HomeScreen

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, StatusBar } from "react-native";
import { STYLES } from "../../styles/Styles";

import {
  Container,
  Header,
  Title,
  Left,
  Icon,
  Right,
  Button,
  Body,
  Content,
  Text,
  Card,
  CardItem
} from "native-base";

const Home = props => {
  closeDrawer = () => {
    this.drawer._root.close();
  };
  openDrawer = () => {
    this.drawer._root.open();
  };

  return (
    <Container>
      <Header style={STYLES.bgAzulPatios}>
        <Left>
          <Button transparent onPress={() => props.navigation.openDrawer()}>
            <Icon name="menu" />
          </Button>
        </Left>
        <Body>
          <Title>HomeScreen</Title>
        </Body>
        <Right />
      </Header>
      <Content padder>
        <Card>
          <CardItem>
            <Body>
              <Text>  Home</Text>
              <Button
                style={STYLES.bgAzulPatios}
                iconLeft
                onPress={() => props.navigation.push("ContainerDetail")}
              >
                <Icon name="arrow-forward" />
                <Text>Container Detail</Text>
              </Button>
            </Body>
          </CardItem>
        </Card>
      </Content>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

app.js

```
.
.
.
 render() {
  return (

      <UserNavigation />
  );
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake you are doing here is Login is a different stack and you should not add your detailed screen as a part of Login

Reason: You are making Login as different stack so that when user logs in and even if he presses back button as we came to different stack there is no page behind so the app closes without going to Login Page. So here if you add Detailed Page as a part of login stack it doesnot work

Solution: For Home create another homeStackRoutingComponent with pages like home, detailed and add that as a screen for home

Ex: Home: {
        screen: homeStackComponent
       }

Here homeStackComponent contains a Stack Container with home, detailed routes with initial route as home :)

Comment: Your answers are the best, but I still don't understand what I should do so that the sidemenu doesn't appear in detailScreen. This does not appear on HomeScreen, but if I do this, the sidemenu is shown in detailScreen

https://i.imgur.com/WdgeXBK.jpg

Comment: Thanks :) and if u don't want sidebar then go in this way... Login with a separate stack navigator and u have that.. now create another stack navigator with all the screens which don't need drawer and add drawer navigator also as on of the object

Comment: but then if I do this home will not be the father of the detail screen ..

Comment: navigationOptions: { drawerLockMode: 'locked-closed' } 
Try this for detailed component

Comment: Try this navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({ drawerLockMode: 'locked-closed' })

Comment: U can check docs here https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/drawerlayoutandroid.html#drawerlockmode